# Android Beacon Library - AltBeacon Repository

Tags: altbeacon

With the altbeacon library we face two issues:
1.  https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/issues/589 I know it is known, still it is not possible to use the library with the library crashing randomly (also on Samsung S8+ with latest updates). The app that is using the library also crashes when app is in foreground all the time (display is always on).
2.  The library stops fetching/recognizing beacon data, when display goes off. So app is running in foreground, all works fine, display is turned off, app stops fetching beacon data from that second. If you switch on the display again then you can see that the app is fetching data again immediately.

Who can help to fix this two issues?

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0):

The second issue you describe should not happen with the library of properly used, so you likely need to treoubleshoot your app.  Here are the steps I would take:

1. Repeat your tests with the [reference application](https://github.com/altbeacon/android-beacon-library-reference) which is known to work to detect beacons with the screen off.  Verify it works for you.
2. Look for differences between your app and the reference app in the way beacon detection is set up.  Make changes to make your app more like the reference app until the screen off issue goes away.

If you need help with item 2 after first trying yourself, please open a new question showing your setup code and describing in greater detail exactly what method calls are not made when the screen is off. (You can link to that new question from here.)

For the first item, this is a known issue we are troubleshooting with the library and we will hopefully have a fix soon to prevent the crashes from showing up on reports or being visible to users.  That said, I do not believe the crashes actually stop detections, they just delay detections until the next Android Scheduled Job cycle.

Understand that this is library is free, open source and a volunteer effort, so we need folks like you to contribute to resolve these kinds of problems.

Full disclosure: I am the lead developer on the Android Beacon Library open source project.